# music plays for a while then stops

Tags: sound, music, streaming

I have a song streaming from Firefox, it is 1 hour long. During that time, I will be doing other things. Formerly, it would stream until the end of  the song. 
Now what seems to happen is the song streams for while after the screen lock comes on, but a few minutes later, playback stops. I want my screen to lock, since I might wander off, but, I want playback to continue? Why is this happening now? how can I go back to what it was, where audio would stream even after the screen would lock?

I also do not understand why it continues to play for a time between the screen lock and the time when it cuts out.

It works fine, as long as I am logged in, and once I log back in, it continues where it left off.